# Why only one value is written to the dictionary?

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

to_write = {}
link = 'https://www.flashscore.ru/'

def get_shedule_data(link):
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get(link)
        time.sleep(15)
        root_div = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.sportName').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(root_div, 'lxml')
        all_events = soup.find_all('div', class_='event__match')
        for event in all_events:
            team1 = event.find('div', class_='event__participant--home').text
            team2 = event.find('div', class_='event__participant--away').text
            to_write['team1'] = team1
            to_write['team2'] = team2
        print(to_write)

    finally:

        browser.quit()

def main():
    get_shedule_data(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

{'team1': 'Маккаби Нетания (Изр)', 'team2': 'Бейтар Тель Авив (Изр)'} is printed, but I expected every team1 and team2 value to be added to the dictionary. I understand it so: all_events is a list. By using for we take every element of all_event, take team1, team2 values from it and write them into dictionary. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Dictionaries can map only one value to a key. If you assign another value to the same key, the last value is overwritten.

Comment: In what way do you want each team to be in the dict? As a list like in `{"team1":["Team Foo", "Team Bar"]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in dictionary, a unique **key** can have only one associated value with it

try these for instance

```py
dict1 = {"a": 1, "a": 2}
```

in this case `dict1` will only contain `{"a":2}` , that is because when you assign new value to same key , it overrides the previous value.

that is how dictionaries work

you can definitely have a **list** to store multiple values associated to a key if you like

```py
dict2 = {"a" : [1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you loop you assign new values each time to team1 and team2.
So each time you overwrite the two keys "team1" and "team2".